# How to aggregate the shortest path values of all nodes?

Tags: python, networkx

```
# sum the lengths to individual nodes
new_dict = {node1: sum([length for length in spl[node1].values()]) for node1 in spl.keys()}
# print the lengths
for node,length in new_dict.items():
    print('The sum of lengths from node {} to all other nodes is {}.'.format(node,length))**
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kR03R.png)

Comment: I can't reproduce your error.  Your code executes correctly for me as written.  Did you maybe run some Jupyter notebook cells out of order so `spl` isn't what is defined above?

Comment: I've solved the problem, as you said, the running order of the cells, thank you